# frequency of items in int[] as opposed to List<Integer>?

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out how to get the frequency of items within a list.  When I approach this problem I typically, in the past, did:

```
int occurrences = Collections.frequency(list, 0);
```

It works when my list is a `List<Integer> list`.  Is there a way to do this if I'm using `int[] list`? When I try collections, my list gets converted and then my code breaks. I can convert my code if needed, but was wondering, if there was a way to get the frequency from int[] instead.

Comment: by writing your own function :) It's one `for-loop`...

Comment: @userunknown sorry, I was composing the question while testing it and got my thoughts mixed up.  I think I fixed it, sorry about that. Might be a sign thats its time to go to bed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (1) write your own linear-time `frequency` method, or (2) convert to an array of boxed int types and use `Arrays.asList` with `Collections.frequency`.

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3};
Integer[] boxedArr = new Integer[arr.length];
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    boxedArr[i] = arr[i];
System.out.println(Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(boxedArr), 1));
```

Comment: I'm guessing from the [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10133584/422353) that this did not worked in the end because is an array of primitive `int`'s.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a `List` from the `int[]`, but otherwise, you just have to write your own.

```
int[] l = //your data;
List<Integer> list = new List<Integer>();
for(int i : l)
  list.add(i);

int o = Collections.frequency(list, 0);
```

Or `Arrays.asList(l);` to make it shorter.

Answer (score 2):

```
int occurrences = Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(list), 0);
```

Or if you are against converting it to a list:

```
int occurrences = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
{
    if(list[i] == X) // X being your number to check
        occurrences++;
}
```

Comment: The use of `asList` will not work because is an array of primitives and not objects, but the counting is the the way I'd use since it does not require building new objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way as well.

```
List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(new Integer [] {
      2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
      2, 3, 4, 5,
      2, 3, 4,
      2, 3,
      2
    });

  System.out.println(" count " + Collections.frequency(intList, 6));
```