# Why is Collections.frequency not working as expected on converted list?

Tags: java

I have used Collections.frequency in the past and its worked fine but I'm having problems now that I'm using an int[].

Basically Collections.frequency requires a array but my data is in the form of a int[] so I convert my list but am not getting an results. I think my mistake is in the converting of the list but not sure how to do it.

Here's an example of my problem:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

public class stackexample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] data = new int[] { 5,0, 0, 1};
        int occurrences = Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(data), 0);
        System.out.println("occurrences of zero is " + occurrences); //shows 0 but answer should be 2
    }
}
```

I don't get an error just zero but I get weird data when I try to list the items in `Arrays.asList(data)`, if I just add data directly, it wants to convert my list into `collections<?>`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class stackexample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> values = Arrays.asList( 5, 0, 0, 2 );
        int occurrences = Collections.frequency(values, 0);
        System.out.println("occurrences of zero is " + occurrences); //shows 0 but answer should be 2
    }
}
```

It's because `Arrays.asList` isn't giving you what you think it is:

http://mlangc.wordpress.com/2010/05/01/be-carefull-when-converting-java-arrays-to-lists/

You're getting back a `List` of `int []`, not `int`.

Comment: Thanks so much Duffy, I thought something like this was the problem because I couldn't do a for loop on the converted list.  But is it possible to convert my list from the existing format to this? my core data is in int[] and it'll be a bit hard to change the input so I was trying to convert it into a new list instead to do this test.

Comment: The conversion question has been asked [before](http://stackoverflow.com/q/880581/422353) and there is no one-line solution. I feel the easiest way out of this is rolling your own frequency function that works with `int[]`.

Comment: There isn't a one-line solution with the JDK alone, but Guava's [`Ints.asList`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#asList(int...)) would do the job in one line.

Answer (score 4):

You problem is from this instruction `Arrays.asList(data)`.

the return of this method is `List<int[]>` not `List<Integer>`.

here a correct implementation

```
    int[] data = new int[] { 5,0, 0, 1};
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int index = 0; index < data.length; index++)
    {
        intList.add(data[index]);
    }

    int occurrences = Collections.frequency(intList, 0);
    System.out.println("occurrences of zero is " + occurrences);
```

Answer (score 1):

The API expects an `Object`, and primitive types are not objects.  Try this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

public class stackexample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] data = new Integer[] { 5,0, 0, 1};
        int occurrences = Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(data), Integer.valueOf(5));
        System.out.println("occurrences of five is " + occurrences); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting it in int[] is there a way to convert an int[] to Integer[]?

Comment: You can always walk through your int[] and set each element of the Integer[] to the current value.